# Select strings which has max value

Tags: mysql

I have table, in which date is posted daily. Every string has field, with name of weekday. I want to get all strings, which `from_sale` has max value, among all the Fridays. Something like this:

```
select *
from deliverability.test_repo
where week_day = 'Friday'
  and from_sale having max(from_sale)
```

But it returned only one string. How can I get all strings?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TYPE, MAX(from_sale), week_day
FROM deliverability.test_repo
WHERE week_day = 'Friday'
GROUP BY TYPE, week_day
```